# DDEV port conflicts on port 443 (plesk?)

Tags: typo3, ddev

Suddenly, I had database connection problems at TYPO3 instance (`An exception occurred in the driver: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`). So I thought maybe a restart would solve the problem because I couldn't think of something that I had done that caused the problem. But with a restart, I have a new problem:

```
ddev restart
Restarting project TYPO3...
Container ddev-TYPO3-db  Removed
Container ddev-TYPO3-web  Removed
Network ddev-typo3_default  Removed
Network ddev-typo3_default  Created
Container ddev-TYPO3-web  Started
Container ddev-TYPO3-db  Started
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ddev-router (03945f5b287d05770888b6e6fbdfe19f9db63191243f9fdb2276b91e1d3411d0): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
Failed to restart TYPO3: failed to start ddev-router: ComposeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-TYPO3 docker-compose -f /home/typo3/.ddev/.router-compose-full.yaml -p ddev-router up -d', action='[-p ddev-router up -d]', err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='Container ddev-router  Creating
Container ddev-router  Created
Container ddev-router  Starting
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ddev-router (03945f5b287d05770888b6e6fbdfe19f9db63191243f9fdb2276b91e1d3411d0): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use'
```

Seems I have a problem with the ports. For the setup, I had followed this setup: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/topics/hosting/

With the command `docker ps -a` I get the following result:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                   PORTS                                               NAMES
39b8ee782ba0   drud/ddev-router:v1.21.5-built                        "/app/docker-entrypo…"   8 minutes ago   Created                                                                      ddev-router
07372d7725d1   drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.4:v1.21.5-TYPO3-built   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes (healthy)   127.0.0.1:49162->3306/tcp                           ddev-TYPO3-db
a8c012aa3b04   drud/ddev-webserver-prod:v1.21.5-TYPO3-built          "/start.sh"              8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes (healthy)   127.0.0.1:49160->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49159->443/tcp   ddev-TYPO3-web
```

I think that is fine.

`sudo lsof -i:443` and `sudo lsof -i:80` returns:

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   2819  root    6u  IPv4  39640      0t0  TCP <hiding>.plesk.page:https (LISTEN)
nginx   2820 nginx    6u  IPv4  39640      0t0  TCP <hiding>.plesk.page:https (LISTEN)
```

I also tried to kill `nginx` and stop `apach2` and freshly started `ddev`, but it will also start `nginx`.

`sudo kill 2819 && sudo service apache2 stop && ddev restart`

```
Restarting project TYPO3...
Container ddev-TYPO3-db  Removed
Container ddev-TYPO3-web  Removed
Network ddev-typo3_default  Removed
Network ddev-typo3_default  Created
Container ddev-TYPO3-web  Started
Container ddev-TYPO3-db  Started
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ddev-router (b51bba1702f68372784247c0bc1a964d547905e2b6badf49a55ac0f1261bf9bf): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
Failed to restart TYPO3: failed to start ddev-router: ComposeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-TYPO3 docker-compose -f /home/typo3/.ddev/.router-compose-full.yaml -p ddev-router up -d', action='[-p ddev-router up -d]', err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='Container ddev-router  Creating
Container ddev-router  Created
Container ddev-router  Starting
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ddev-router (b51bba1702f68372784247c0bc1a964d547905e2b6badf49a55ac0f1261bf9bf): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use'
```

And now I have no idea what I have or where to configure.

Best Regards, and Thank You for your help

#### Update:

Ok, some weird things. I can't remove `nginx` from Ubuntu, because it is not installed. So, I have no idea why nginx is listed as the command. But I could solve the problem by killing the process and immediately starting the container via docker. The database connection is working now, too. I am not fine with that solution, but my server instance is working for now. If you have an idea, of what I have to reconfigure, please let me know.

Comment: `nginx` is listed because on Linux, the processes running inside the containers are shown in the OS listing. So the `nginx` you're seeing is probably the one in `ddev-webserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically a `ddev`/`docker` issue and not related to TYPO3.

The ddev start notices the `nginx` as it is the used software for the global ddev `router` container. And that container cannot be started due to port conflicts.

```
listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
```

That means, that something else is directly running on port 443 for all interfaces.

The `ddev` project has a troubleshooting chapter, specially one for occupied ports which can be found here: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#web-server-ports-already-occupied

Your result for port check commands

```
$ sudo lsof -i:443 and sudo lsof -i:80
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   2819  root    6u  IPv4  39640      0t0  TCP <hiding>.plesk.page:https (LISTEN)
nginx   2820 nginx    6u  IPv4  39640      0t0  TCP <hiding>.plesk.page:https (LISTEN)
```

states that a software directly runs on your host with the name `<hiding>.plesk.page:https`.

Do you have by any change the `plesk` server administration software installed / available on your server ? If yes, that package provides webserver by default. You need to disable it there (if possible) - or run the ddev stuff on non-default ports (reconfiguring ddev) and than proxy that in some way.

Shortly said - you have conflicting software on your system.

I'm not firm with PLESK or any of these fancy admin panel software and therefore cannot help more.

It may be, that plesk installs ngnix directly and not from OS (Ubunutu) packages - or spawning them as docker container.

You need to identify that and where the block is comming from. If not directly on your server, you can check if some docker container are running:

```
# display running container
$ docker ps 

# display all container, even stopped container
$ docker ps -a
```

Maybe there is a container hanging around binding on port 80 and/or 443.

If it is a ddev container, maybe it get stalled somehow. That's also covered somewhere in the ddev documentation if I remember it correctly (sry, also not using ddev personally).

From the port troubleshooting section:

```
# Stop all Docker containers that might be using the port by running:
$ ddev poweroff && \
    docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)

# then restart docker (depends on your os, debian/ubuntu in newer
# version maybe
$ systemctl restart docker
# or for older versions
$ service docker restart
```

Additionally, and maybe you should start with the generic ddev troubleshooting list here: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#general-troubleshooting-strategies

**General Troubleshooting Strategies**

- Start by running ddev poweroff to make sure all containers can start fresh.
- Temporarily disable firewalls, VPNs, network proxies, and virus checkers
  while you’re troubleshooting.
- Temporarily disable any proxies you’ve established in Docker’s settings.
- Use ddev debug dockercheck and ddev debug test to help sort out Docker
  problems.
- On macOS, check to make sure Docker Desktop or Colima are not out of disk
  space. In Settings (or Preferences) → Resources → Disk image size there
  should be ample space left; try not to let usage exceed 80% because the
  reported number can be unreliable. If it says zero used, something is
  wrong.
- If you have customizations like PHP overrides, nginx or Apache overrides,
  MySQL/PostgreSQL overrides, custom services, or config.yaml changes, please
  back them out while troubleshooting. It’s important to have the simplest
  possible environment while troubleshooting.
- Restart Docker. Consider a Docker factory reset in serious cases, which
  will destroy any databases you’ve loaded. See Docker Troubleshooting for
  more.
- Try the simplest possible DDEV project (like ddev debug test does):

```
ddev poweroff
mkdir ~/tmp/testddev
cd ~/tmp/testddev
ddev config --auto
printf "<?php\nphpinfo();\n" > index.php
ddev start
```

- If that starts up fine, there may be an issue specifically with the project you’re trying to start.